# Magento 2.4.4 Setup with Docker on Ubuntu

Tags: magento-upgrade, magento2.4.4

I want to setup Magento 2.4.4 on Ubuntu using Docker. Please someone guide me through.
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your best bet is to use either:

- https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento (Mark Shust)
- https://github.com/cmtickle/docker-lemp-stack (Author: Colin Tickle)

I have used the latter and did like it. Like everything you will have to expect to have to spend 1 week or 2 where you are not as productive and this will be before things get better.

Unfortunately, there is no magic recipe. Once installed, docker remains still a devops type of exercise where every problem can be simple or complex depending on your OS used, your modules used and the requirements overall you're having in your site.